# How to pull the vedio link name imbeded in a web page along with vedio name

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, pandas, web-scripting

I am trying to pull all the video link reference from the web page along with video names, i have tried below code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib
url = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.ansible.com/resources/videos').read()
acc_link = BeautifulSoup(url, features="lxml")
for line in acc_link.find_all('a'):
    print(line.get('href'))
```

**Output:**

```
https://www.ansible.com/?hsLang=en-us
https://www.ansible.com/overview/it-automation?hsLang=en-us
https://www.ansible.com/overview/it-automation?hsLang=en-us
https://www.ansible.com/overview/how-ansible-works?hsLang=en-us
https://www.ansible.com/products/automation-platform?hsLang=en-us
https://www.ansible.com/use-cases?hsLang=en-us
https://www.ansible.com/use-cases/provisioning?hsLang=en-us
https://www.ansible.com/use-cases/configuration-management?hsLang=en-us
https://www.ansible.com/use-cases/application-deployment?hsLang=en-us
https://www.ansible.com/use-cases/continuous-delivery?hsLang=en-us
https://www.ansible.com/use-cases/security-automation?hsLang=en-us
https://www.ansible.com/use-cases/orchestration?hsLang=en-us
https://www.ansible.com/integrations?hsLang=en-us
```

**HTML source code for example:**

```
<h4><a href="https://www.ansible.com/resources/webinars-training/ansible-network-automation-with-arista-cloudvision-and-arista?hsLang=en-us">Ansible Network Automation with Arista CloudVision and Arista Validated Designs</a></h4>
```

Like above is just an example for the HTML source code of the link https://www.ansible.com/resources/videos i want link name as `https://www.ansible.com/resources/webinars-training/ansible-network-automation-with-arista-cloudvision-and-arista` and vedio name `Ansible Network Automation with Arista CloudVision and Arista Validated Designs` .

**Below is just another example** where i want `href` before `?` and `a` value ie `Scale-out Clustering with Tower 3.1`.

`<h4><a href="https://www.ansible.com/scale-out-clustering-tower?hsLang=en-us">Scale-out Clustering with Tower 3.1</a></h4>`

**Desired output:**

**Vedio Name:** Ansible Network Automation with Arista CloudVision and Arista Validated Designs

**Vedio Link:** https://www.ansible.com/resources/webinars-training/ansible-network-automation-with-arista-cloudvision-and-arista

Thanks for the help in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `href` from all anchors then you can use a css select `'a[href]'` which will only find anchor tags that have `href` attributes:

You indeed tweak a little bit as follows,

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib

url = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.ansible.com/resources/videos').read()
acc_link = BeautifulSoup(url, features="lxml")

for article in acc_link.find_all('div', class_='card-body'):
        # this will grab the name of the video article
        headline1 = article.h4.a.text
        # this will get your video link
        headline2 = article.select_one('a[href]')['href'].split('?')[0]
        #headline2 = headline2.split('?')[0]
        print(headline1)
        # I have placed the condition as few of the link address do not have
        #  the site link prefix www.ansible.com.
        if 'www' in headline2:
            print(headline2)
        else:
            print('https://www.ansible.com' + headline2)
        print()
```

**Result:**

```
Automating Monitoring with the Sensu Go Ansible Collection
https://www.ansible.com/resources/webinars-training/automating-monitoring-with-the-sensu-go-ansible-collection

How to load balance a hybrid cloud using Red Hat Insights,  Red Hat Ansible, and Red Hat AMQ Interconnect
https://www.redhat.com/en/about/videos/road-to-open-hybrid-cloud-part-2

British Army speeds service delivery with Red Hat
https://www.redhat.com/en/about/videos/british-army-speeds-service-delivery-red-hat

Zero To 100 - Rapid deployment with Ansible Tower
https://www.ansible.com/zero-to-100

Scale-out Clustering with Tower 3.1
https://www.ansible.com/scale-out-clustering-tower

What's New In Tower 3.1
https://www.ansible.com/whats-new-tower-3-1

Amelco - Continuous Delivery with Ansible Tower
https://www.ansible.com/success-stories/amelco

Runnable - Getting Started with Ansible
https://www.ansible.com/success-stories/runnable

Fatmap - App Deployment with Ansible
https://www.ansible.com/success-stories/fatmap

Splunk and Ansible Tower
https://www.ansible.com/success-stories/splunk

Siemens - Delivering Automation to the Cloud
https://www.ansible.com/success-stories/siemens

Ansible Tower 10 min demo
https://www.ansible.com/products/tower/demo

Ansible Tower 3.1
https://www.ansible.com/tower-workflows-demo

Ansible Tower 2-min Overview
https://www.ansible.com/tower-overview

Ansible Quick Start
https://www.ansible.com/resources/videos/quick-start-video

Ansible + AWS - Serverless Deploys
https://www.ansible.com/resources/videos/ansible-aws-automate-serverless-application-deploys-with-ansible

Ansible + AWS - EC2 Provisionling
https://www.ansible.com/resources/videos/ansible-aws-automate-ec2-provisioning-with-red-hat-ansible-engine-and-red-hat-ansible-tower

Network Automation For Beginners
https://www.ansible.com/resources/videos/network-automation-with-red-hat-ansible-engine-for-beginners

Agnostic Network Automation Examples with Ansible and Juniper NRE Labs
https://www.ansible.com/blog/agnostic-network-automation-examples-with-ansible-and-juniper-nre-labs

 How useful is Ansible in a cloud-native Kubernetes environment
https://www.ansible.com/blog/how-useful-is-ansible-in-a-cloud-native-kubernetes-environment
```

I hope this will helpful.